# Science and philosophy: how to study the issue of mind

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, mind-body, cognitive-sciences

**Short background**

The issue of mind has perturbed me for many years, and still does. It is common to hear questions like: *What is life*, or *matter* or *anything*, I used to wonder about mind, so asked: *what is mind?* 
To be clear, I call mind to an idea or a thought, also dreams are pure mind-things.

Days ago something suggested that science can't answer a question about *'what is' something*. Why not? Because science has been always all about how things work, not what they are. Even Schrodinger on its book *What is life?* Finally explores *How is life produced?* What things are is a matter of definitions (I know it is not that simple). Of course, models are a way to define what things are, but they really exist as useful ways to understand the behaviour of things, not as reality. So there we have, for example, the atomic model.

**Some general questions**

Naturally, there appeared new questions about mind. It has no scientifical sense to ask what is mind, although I suppose we can ask:

1. why do we see, hear, and even suffer in dreams;
2. how mind acts over brain (and the opposite).

This last question is particularly interesting because of its relation to free will.

**Specific question to this forum**

I posted here because I'm interested on the scientificalness of the previous questions, I mean, **if the previous are valid questions to study scientifically**. It'd be greatly appreciated if you can add some scientific studies about the problem.

Comment: Broad and vague questions like "why do we see" or "how mind acts" are not well suited for SE, they are better addressed by googling and reading online encyclopedias. Please reduce the scope to a single specific question answerable within reasonable space.

Comment: @Conifold I agree. I'm not asking for the answer, but for some help (interesting authors or books or ideas to start with)

Comment: There are many articles about the mind. You may try the following articles; they may be interesting to you and may answer some of your questions:  [Leibniz's Philosophy of Mind](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz-mind/), [The Computational Theory of Mind](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computational-mind/), and [The Basic Theory of the Mind](https://mindtheory.net/).

Comment: An important distinction.  Science cannot tell you whether a baseball is really a collection of atoms, or if it is an illusion of a physical object drempt up by a dreaming mind, or if the matrix has you and that baseball is really just a pile of code.  That's what they mean by "science cannot tell you what something is."  The thing science can tell you is predictions about how something will behave.  Science *can* tell you that when someone throws it at your head, you should duck because all evidence suggests it's going to hurt, no matter what it actually is.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'these reasonings'. If you mean the idea that (empirical or natural) science cannot study the mind then this seems a matter of common sense. Science studies brains. It cannot find minds but must extrapolates from observed behaviour. (cf. Skinner. Behaviourism etc.) The study of mind requires a different kind of science.

Comment: @user287279 i'm asking for scientific studies, more than philosophical, but I think the problem is mainly philosophical...

Comment: @CortAmmon Yes, thanks for the comment. That's precisely what I've tried to say, do you mean it is unclear?

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks. I think science can study the mind. Science can study anything in terms of causality, and it is studying how mind is produced by the brain and body. What I'm saying is that  science can not study what something is, as Cort Ammon said in his comment...; although you probably meant the same...

Comment: I was confused by the phrase, "models are a way to define what things are," along with the specific example of atomic theory.  A lot of people believe that atoms are things that exist.  Between those two wordings, I wanted to make sure the distinction was clear.

Comment: @CortAmmon yes, that's fine. I am on that line too. However, I suspect things also don't exist, it is a matter of evolution and beliefs (in this order). At least, I think someone could hold that atoms exist. I avoided that problem by saying atoms are just useful tools etc...

Comment: I'd place thinking someone could hold that atoms exist could be placed in a category along with thinking that I can convey meaning using words.  Proving them to be true is frustratingly difficult, but so is trying to do anything without assuming them.

Comment: @CortAmmon Yes, perfectly pointed. Now suppose those two agree in proving existence of atoms. Then they are believing not to senses (as it was usual, and so I'm saying we trust our senses) but to machines...that's like a second problem. Again, that's why I said models *might be regarded* as reality...but I might change that...

Comment: "science can't answer a question about 'what is' something" - neither philosophy. Philosophy does not give names. Science does not give names. But names are within foundations of science, philosophy and even some arts.

Comment: @rus9384 yes you seem right, but philosophy has largely been devoted to that questions... don't you think?

Comment: I'd say it was philosophers' mistake. A question "What is X?" either is declarative or descriptive. If it's descriptive then it is reduced to "What do people mean when speaking about X?" and it lies within the methods of science. If it's declarative, then it is just a definition: "We call this phone iPhone X" and has no philosophical meaning. Philosophy comes to work only after there is a consensus regarding the name, it is examing properties which cannot be studied scientifically. And "What should be called X?" is not a question of philosophy, as it is just a personal preference.

Comment: "We live in a world made of kisses, not of stones" - Carlo Rovelli. Everything is process https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_physics#Wheeler's_"it_from_bit"

Comment: @[santimirandarp](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/29573/santimirandarp). One of the articles I suggest - [The Basic Theory of the Mind](https://mindtheory.net/) - is a scientific theory based on scientific evidence and with testable predictions. I think it’s an interesting theory. If you had time, please check it out.

Comment: @user287279 thanks for your patience. I will...

Answer (score 2):

A key concept for making sense of questions like these is the verb "to supervene."   A supervenes on B iff all properties of A are explained by B.  As a practical example, all of the rules of how to put together circuits that an electrical engineer might learn *supervene* on the laws of physics -- in particular Maxwell's equations.  Everything you can say about circuits can be said using physics phrasings.

A major outstanding question in philosophy today is whether "mental states" supervene on "brain states" or not.  In other words, is our concept of the mind *purely* a pattern derived from brain states, or is there something else.

If one were to assume that mental states supervene on brain states, then it would be easy to talk about what we say/hear in scientific terms, and explore them scientifically.  However, that assumption itself is quite a tricky one.

A related question is whether the universe supervenes on mathematics or not.  Is the universe *defined* as a mathematical structure, or is mathematics something that humans have constructed to make sense of the universe.  Again, such a question is still outstanding.  From what I understand, most philosophers currently believe such a question cannot be answered.

Comment: "To supervene" isn't a phrase I've heard before.  It seems like a perfect description for how (I believe) the conscious mind and the brain relate to one another.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, **"Why do we see, hear, and even suffer in dreams;"** the brain does not stop operations when you go to sleep.  Far from it, the [mind appears to be quite active](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/what-happens-in-the-brain-during-sleep1/).  Though we aren't 100% sure what the mind is doing with all that activity, [some have linked these times to the brain's logging and sorting data you encountered during the waking day](https://www.reddit.com/r/JordanPeterson/comments/8f1njr/joe_rogan_podcast_with_sleep_specialist_great_for/). In other words, it's taking the things that impacted your life today, and processes them to perhaps improve your ability to handle those same things tomorrow.

As for the second question, **"How mind acts over brain (and the opposite)?"** I'm afraid it's not quite a sensible question, as far as the science goes.  While the jury is still out on exactly what the consciousness mind is ([definitions vary widely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness)), the evidence points toward "the mind" as a subjective interpretation of the various activities of our physical brain.  The correlation between [brain activity and conscious thought](https://www.mpg.de/5839948/conscious_perception) is well documented, though not necessarily well understood.  That tells me they are likely different facets of the same system, and not separate systems which compete for dominance/control.